# Digest認証ありのPOSTリクエストにおいて、HTTPボディが空になる

Tags: windows, .net

＃同じ質問をわんくま同盟でも同じ質問をさせていただいております。

現在Windows10Mobileを利用したアプリを開発中です。
Windows10MobileアプリではHttpClientクラスを利用する必要があると認識しており、
環境の構成上、Digest認証後にPOSTリクエストを送信する必要があります。

いくらかプログラムしてみましたがエラーとなっています。
HTTPの内容を確認したところHTTPヘッダの「Content-Length」は正しく設定されていますが、
肝心のHTTPボディにPOSTパラメータが設定されていません。

以下にサンプルコードを記載させていただきますが、何か不備等はございませんでしょうか。
お分かりになる範囲でご教授いただければ幸いです。

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Http

Public Class Class1
 Public Async Function registOrderInfo() As Task(Of String)

 Dim url As Uri = New Uri("http://test.com/test/testGet.cgi")
 Dim sysHandler As HttpClientHandler = New HttpClientHandler()
 sysHandler.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("testuser", "testpass") 'Digest認証用アカウント
Dim client As HttpClient = New HttpClient(sysHandler)

 Try
 Dim param As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String)) = New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))
 param.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("test1", "aaa"))
 param.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("test2", "bbb"))

 Dim content As HttpContent = New FormUrlEncodedContent(param)
 Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await client.PostAsync(url, content)

 Dim statusCode As HttpResponseMessage = response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
 Dim message As String = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
 Catch ex As Exception
 httpResponseBody = "Error: " + ex.HResult.ToString("X") + " Message: " + ex.Message
 End Try

 Return ""
 End Function

End Class
```

（1月11日追記）
今更ながら気がついて大変申し訳ございませんが、
今回Digest認証を実施している関係上、2回アクセスします。

1回目は当然、401で返ってくるのですが、その1回目のhttpRequestのBodyにはPOSTパラメータが設定されていますが、2回目のhttpRequestのBodyが空でRequestされていました。

1回目と2回目のアクセスはPostAsyncの中で実行されていると理解していますが、
本事象を解決する方法はありませんでしょうか。

Comment: たぶんマルチポスト https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/4e0e9a4d-f594-4579-a7d6-4c0682d486c3/httpclientpost?forum=winstoreapp

Answer (score 1):

> 1回目は当然、401で返ってくるのですが、その1回目のhttpRequestのBodyにはPOSTパラメータが設定されていますが、2回目のhttpRequestのBodyが空でRequestされていました。
>
> 1回目と2回目のアクセスはPostAsyncの中で実行されていると理解していますが、
> 本事象を解決する方法はありませんでしょうか。

認証を要求される場面で、未認証状態のままデータを`POST`すべきではありません。理由としては

- 認証が通るとは限らない
- その状態で`POST`データを送り込むのはサーバーからみてDoS攻撃になりかねない
- クライアントからみて情報漏洩になりかねない

そのため、`HttpClient`クラスは暗黙的に２度もデータを`POST`しない仕様になっているのかもしれません。

---

本筋としてはpgrhoさんの提案されている`PreAuthenticate`なのですが、Digest認証ではサーバーから`nonce`を受け取らないことにはハッシュ値を計算できないため原理上PreAuthenticateできません。

同サーバーに対していずれかのページへ`GET`アクセスし、事前にDigest認証を完了させてから`POST`できないでしょうか？

Comment: お返事ありがとうございます。やはり困難そうであるということで理解いたしました。

`GET`した後に`POST`となるとパスワードの暗号化などの処理も必要ということで少々開発時間が掛かりそうです。他方式でアクセス出来ないか検討させていただきます。

Answer (score 0):

`HttpClientHandler`の`PreAuthenticate`プロパティを指定する必要があるのでは。

```
sysHandler.PreAuthenticate = True
```

Comment: 試させていただきましたが、状況に変わりはありませんでした。